# Can't load OpenGL procs, but only from Haskell

Tags: windows, opengl, haskell, openglraw

I've had a problem after converting some C++ code to Haskell on Windows. The code in C++ works fine, but in Haskell any OpenGL function fails to load, i.e.

```
user error (unknown OpenGL extension entry glGenVertexArrays, check for
OpenGL 3.1)
```

Whereas the function works fine in C++ (where I'm using glLoadGen). I've loaded both into `depends.exe` and don't see any difference in what they use from OpenGL32.dll.

I'm using `OpenGLRaw-1.3.0.0`.

Comment: Any reason you are using `OpenGLRaw` instead of `OpenGL`? Can you run a simple example program at all, or is it just `glGenVertexArrays` which gives the error?

Comment: I am using OpenGl, but the version of that shouldn't matter. Any it's any non 1.1 function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by trying to call GL functions before calling `Graphics.UI.GLFW.makeContextCurrent`. There needs to be a current context before any GL functions are available.